# How to write this sql query more efficiently

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here I have a query where I am selecting the values which are in a range 14 days back

```
DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME  
SET @DATETIMENOW = GETDATE()

SELECT
        B.WEEK AS PREVIOUSWEEKACCIDENTS
    FROM BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CI
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT Distinct
                CHINFO.CHILDID,
                COUNT(*) as week
            FROM
                BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO               
            JOIN 
                BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE 
                    ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID
            JOIN
                BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP 
                    ON  CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID                         
            WHERE 
            (
                   CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT'
                OR 
               (
                       CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK'
                   AND 
                       CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS' 
                   AND
                       CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'
               )
            )  
            AND 
                CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN 
                        DATEADD(
                            DD,
                            -(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-14)-1),
                             @DATETIMENOW-14) 
                    AND  
                        DATEADD(
                            DD,
                            7-(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-14)),
                            @DATETIMENOW-14)
        group by
            CHINFO.CHILDID
    ) b
        on CI.ChildID = b.ChildID
```

What I need here is to select the same values which are in a range of 7 days back that is @DATETIMENOW-7 is the only change and it has to be a single query.Any suggestion?

Comment: My initial suggestion is to write a better question. Its polite to spend as much time writing a question as you anticipate others will spend answering it. Less alturisticly, it massively increases the chance of getting an answer. I've put some effort into making your TSQL human readable, this is because your are new and I'd like you to learn from my example.

Comment: do you really need a single statement, or a single batch?  I understand if you are a programmer and need a single "command" - like a typical query from ado.net.  But you can actually send a whole batch, with multiple statements like these answers.

Answer (score 1):

okay, there are some calculations in the statement that will always give the same value.

```
DECLARE @now DateTime;
DECLARE @start DateTime;
DECLARE @end DateTime;

SET @now = getDate();
SET @start = DATEADD(
                 DD,
                 -(DATEPART(DW, @now - 14) - 1),
                 @now - 14); 
SET @end = DATEADD(
               DD,
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, @now - 14)),
               @now - 14);
```

If you do them up front like this, then it will clearly avoid repeating them for each row and make your TSQL more readable.

---

Next, the outer select doesn't do anything apart from change the name of column in the set,

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) PREVIOUSWEEKSACCIDENTS
    FROM [BKA].[CHILDINFORMATION] ci               
    JOIN [BKA].[CHILDEVENTS] ce 
        ON ce.[CHILDID] = ci.[CHILDID]
    JOIN [BKA].[CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES] ce 
        ON  ce.[EVENTID] = ce.[EVENTID]                         
    WHERE 
            (
                ce.[TYPE] = 'ACCIDENT'
            OR 
                (
                    ce.[TYPE] = 'POTTYBREAK'
                AND 
                    ce.[PROPERTY] = 'SUCCESS' 
                AND
                    cep.[PROPERTYVALUE] = 'FALSE'
                )
            )  
        AND 
            CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @start AND @end 
    GROUP BY
        ci.[CHILDID];
```

So, this statement would achieve the same result.

Comment: thanks..here my actual question is like I need to get the result in a single query for both last 7 days and last 14 days..that too in a single query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, -( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 14) - 1 ), @DATETIMENOW - 14);
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, 7 - ( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 14) ), @DATETIMENOW - 14);

SELECT  COUNT(*) AS PREVIOUSWEEKACCIDENTS
FROM    BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO
        JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID
        JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP ON CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID
WHERE   (
          CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT'
          OR (
               CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'
             )
        )
        AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY CHINFO.CHILDID
```

Comment: In your query you have unnecessarily added a left join. And also you don't require DISTINCT in your select clause when you are using group by assuming you don't have duplicate rows.

Comment: Additionally, you'd be better editing your question, rather than commenting on it.

Comment: thanks..here my actual question is like I need to get the result in a single query for both last 7 days and last 14 days..that too in a single query

Answer (score 1):

```
@Rooney just check if this helps you:

    DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @StartDate7 DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, -( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 7) - 1 ), @DATETIMENOW - 7);
    DECLARE @StartDate14 DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, -( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 14) - 1 ), @DATETIMENOW - 14);
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DD, 7 - ( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 14) ), @DATETIMENOW - 14);

    SELECT  CHE.Category,
            COUNT(*) AS PREVIOUSWEEKACCIDENTS
            FROM BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO
            JOIN (
                    SELECT ADDDATE,
                           'Last7Days' Category
                        FROM BKA.CHILDEVENTS
                        WHERE CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @StartDate7 AND @EndDate

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT ADDDATE,
                           'Last14Days' Category
                        FROM BKA.CHILDEVENTS
                        WHERE CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @StartDate14 AND @EndDate

                 ) CHE 
                ON CHINFO.CHILDID = CHE.CHILDID
                    AND CHINFO.ADDDATE = CHE.ADDDATE 
            JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP 
                ON CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID
            WHERE   (
                        CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT'
                      OR (
                           CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK'
                           AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'
                           AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'
                         )
                    )
            GROUP BY CHE.Category,
                     CHINFO.CHILDID
```